# BASH getopts Multiple Scripts with Same Options

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, getopts

I have a series of BASH scripts.

I am using getopts to parse arguments from the cmd line (although open to alternatives).

There are a series of common options to these scripts call this options set A
ie queue, ncores etc.

Each script then has a series of extra options ie set B1,B2,B3.

What I want is for script

```
"1 to be able to take options  A+B1"
"2 to be able to take options  A+B2"
"3 to be able to take options  A+B2"
```

But I want to be able to store the code for options A in a central location (library/function) with having to write out in each script.

What I want is a way to insert generic code in getopts. Or alternatively a way to run getopts twice.

In fact I've done this by having getopts as a function which is sourced.

But the problem is I cant get the unrecognised option to work them.
I guess one way would be to remove the arguements from options A from the string before passing to a getopts for B1, B2 , B3 etc ?

Thanks Roger

Comment: What do you mean by "store arguments A in a central location"? Arguments are passed separately to every invocation of a script, not stored anywhere. Are you talking about storing the *code to recognize them* in a central location, or....?

Comment: code to recognize them in a central location, yes

Comment: Can you use `getopt` ?

Comment: Having a choice between `getopts` and `getopt`, I would stick with `getopts`. `getopt` varies widely between different distributions, does destructive argument parsing, and _sometimes_ cannot handle empty argument strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace. Overall `getopts` is a safer and a more reliable choice, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very nice question, to answer which we need to have a good understanding of how `getopts` works.

The key point here is that `getopts` is designed to iterate over the supplied arguments in a single loop. Thus, the solution to the question is to split *the loop* between different files rather then running the command twice:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File_1

getopts_common() {
    builtin getopts ":ab:${1}" ${2} ${@:3} || return 1
    case ${!2} in
        'a')
            echo 'a triggered'
            continue
            ;;
        'b')
            echo "b argument supplied -- ${OPTARG}"
            continue
            ;;
        ':')
            echo "MISSING ARGUMENT for option -- ${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
}

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File_2
# source "File_1"

while getopts_common 'xy:' OPTKEY ${@}; do
    case ${OPTKEY} in
        'x')
            echo 'x triggered'
            ;;
        'y')
            echo "y argument supplied -- ${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        '?')
            echo "INVALID OPTION -- ${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        ':')
            echo "MISSING ARGUMENT for option -- ${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            echo "UNIMPLEMENTED OPTION -- ${OPTKEY}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

## Implementation notes

We start with `File_2` since that's where the execution of the script starts:

- Instead of invoking `getopts` directly, we call it via it's proxy: `getopts_common`, which is responsible for processing all common option.
- `getopts_common` function is invoked with:

  1. A string that defines which options to expect, and where to expect their arguments. This string only covers options defined in `File_2`.
  2. The name of the shell-variable to use for option reporting.
  3. A list of the command line arguments. (This simplifies accessing them from inside `getopts_common` function.)

Moving on to the sourced file (`File_1`) we need to bear in mind that `getopts_common` function *runs inside the while loop* defined in `File_2`:

- `getopts` returns `false` if there is nothing left to parse, `|| return 1` bit insures that `getopts_common` function does the same.
- The execution needs to move on to the next iteration of the loop when a valid option is processed. Hence, each valid option match ends with `continue`.
- Silent error reporting (enabled when OPTSPEC starts with `:`) allows us to distinguish between `INVALID OPTION` and `MISSING ARGUMENT`. The later error is specific to the common options defined in `File_1`, thus it needs to be trapped there.

For more in-depth information on `getopts`, see [Bash Hackers Wiki: Getopts tutorial](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)